# jQuery addClass() on li tab after load()

Tags: jquery, tabs, load, click, preventdefault

I'm trying to use addClass('current') on a li tab. Problem is that the click function calls a load() which resets the current class on the li tab. How do I addClass() after the load() on the li that the visitor clicked on?

How my could looks like now:

```
$('div#container ul.tab-nav li').click(function(event) {
   $('div#container').load('index.htm').fadeIn("slow");
   $('div ul.tab-nav li').removeClass('current');
   $(this).addClass('current');
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}); 

<ul class="tab-nav">
    <li class="current">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently your code after the `.load()` call executes before the AJAX call has been finished. You need to use the success callback of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) to execute your code after the request is complete:

```
$('#container ul.tab-nav li').click(function(event) {
    $('#container').load('index.htm', function() {
        $('div ul.tab-nav li').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Note that you are overwriting the contents of `#container` and thus the click event handler will be lost once new content has been loaded. If this is not what you want, use a delegate by replacing the first line with the following:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'ul.tab-nav li', function(event) {
```

Comment: Can you please show me how it would look like with the click function as well? Thank you

Comment: @user1355815: I considered this trivial. Anyway, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I'm going with your code and the last line that you added in the edit. The problem now is that it adds the current class to the container and not the <li>. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `$(this)` with `$('#container ul.tab-nav li')`

Comment: This will addClass('current') to every <li>

Comment: He's overwriting the whole container anyway and wasn't very clear what exactly he wants...

Answer (score 3):

Put load after changing the class 'current'.

```
$('div#container ul.tab-nav li').click(function(event) {
  $('div ul.tab-nav li').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  $('div#container').load('index.htm').fadeIn("slow");
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery you can execute code when page is loaded :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});
```